# Can i use objectAnimator in xml in api level 2.2?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-xml

Can i use objectAnimator in xml in api level 2.2 for fragment transition to to get more types of animation?? or provide me xml for animations like glide, cube, stack etc provided with API 11 and above wich supports API 8 too.

```
private void transitionFade() {
    mFragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out,android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out);
}
```

The above method with "anim" works fine in API8
but below code doesn't work with "animator"

```
private void transitionGlide() {
    mFragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.glide_fragment_horizontal_in, R.animator.glide_fragment_horizontal_out, R.animator.glide_fragment_horizontal_in, R.animator.glide_fragment_horizontal_out);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot directly, as [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) appeared in API11, however you can try to use backport of Honeycomb Animation system [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/)

Comment: thanks...Marcin Orlowski...can you suggest some another way(code snippet) to achieve same on api8

Comment: NineOldAndroids is what you are looking for as it is basically backport of API11 animation system. Just include into your project. do `import` properly and you should be fine